# Is it possible to add several plots to the same PSpice simulation?

Tags: simulation, spice

I'm using OrCAD Capture/PSpice 16.3 to simulate a MOSFET circuit. One of the difficulties I'm facing is plotting a timing diagram of several voltages. If I simulate the project and choose which voltages I want to plot, they all come out on the same plot.

Now, I can add a new plot to the simulation and move each of the values I want to measure to the new plots, but having to do it manually every time I simulate the circuit becomes tiresome and I was wondering if there was any way to set up multiple plots for a simulation without doing it manually every time.

Comment: (I was browsing the unanswered questions) If it's not too late, I don't know about OrCAD, but I do about LTspice, and one thing related to this is that it allows for adding more than just one plot pane and you can save the results, results which will be automatically loaded at re-opening the schematic for simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I was browsing the unanswered questions like *Vlad* did (see the comment above), so... - maybe it's too late, but what if it can still help... ;-)

This problem can be solved (in *PSpice*) using *command file(s)* the following way:

1. After a simulation delete all traces in the *Probe* window (don't use any probes within the simulated circuit schematic; the *Probe* window is *empty* then)
2. Use *PSpice Probe Menu*/**File**/**Log Commands**...
   Choose a directory and a name for a command file. Its default extension is **cmd**; but it's a **text** (macro) file.

   From this time on all *commands are recorded* in the above file unless you stop it by:

   *PSpice Probe Menu*/**File**/**Log Commands**... (using the same menu item as before).

   During the recording you can ***insert required traces***, ***make calculations*** with trace variables, ***insert new plots***, etc.

   After that (when recording has been stopped), the recorded commands can also be edited in a ("*pure*") text editor. So, when you comprehend the principle by exploring the recorded commands in that file (it's quite easy), you can do "whatever you want" with them  (what is allowed, of course ;-), add some new by hand, etc... (or do nothing, it's up to you).
3. Their use is easy:

   a) Start with an empty *Probe* window (don't use any probes within the schematic diagram)

   b) Use *PSpice Probe Menu*/**File**/**Run Commands**...

   Select the appropriate *command file* (you can have created more than one for one simulation, of course) and...

...that's it.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically run the command every time the simulation is run?